# Assign function inputs to values in global environment

Tags: r

Suppose that I have this function:

```
fun1 <- function(p1, p2, p3){
  temp <-p1+p2+p3 
  return(temp) }
```

And it can be called like this:

```
fun1(p1=1, p2=2, p3=3)
```

For debugging purposes, I would like to assign all function inputs as values in my global environment. **Is there a built-in function that will achive the following?**

```
p1 <- 1
p2 <- 2
p3 <- 3
```

I would like to copy the contents of the function call directly since there are many inputs and I often need to do this. So, I'm looking for a function that works like this:

```
assignVariables(p1=1, p2=2, p3=3)
```

`assign()` is the most similar function that I know, but that would require reformatting the input arguments. I could also use a RegEx to replace the `,` with a newline symbol, but I'm hoping that there's a better way.

Comment: Why don't you set a breakpoint with `browser()` or via an IDE?

Comment: I also thought about that, but then would I still have access to the other variables in the global environment? Essentially, I have some code that mostly fills my requirements as a script and I want to transform it into a function while also improving the function body.

Comment: @Bobby Have you actually given it a try to see if it does what you want?

Comment: I've added `browser()` to my code and executed it: `fun1 <- function(p1, p2, p3){ browser()
  temp <-p1+p2+p3 
  return(temp) }`. This gives me a new prompt called `Browse[1]>`. At this prompt, I see that I can interact with values from the global environment as well as from my function environment. That's great. If I have a value with the same name and different contents, I would get the one from the function environment, right? (It would take precedence?)

Comment: @Bobby: I'll reiterate Dason's comment: Have you tried it to see if it works? This is a pretty easy question to solve via "trying it and seeing". I'd also add that `browser` wouldn't be very useful if it *didn't* do that...

Comment: Thanks for all of the tips. Usually I like to have both a theoretical answer and to test it practically. But here trying it out is enough!